# Abstract PDO Repository File error

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am new in php and I am getting some error lately. Please see my code below.

I'm getting some errors saying that **Using $this when not in object context**.

This is index.php

```
 <?php
        require_once ('setting.php');


        try{

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
                user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                account VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                )";

            $result = $this->db->getConnection()->execute($sql);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo " " . $e->message();
        }

    ?>
```

I name this setting.php

```
<?php
    abstract class PDORepository{
        const USERNAME="xxxx";
        const PASSWORD="";
        const HOST="xxxxxx";
        const DB="xxxxx";

        private function getConnection(){
            $username = self::USERNAME;
            $password = self::PASSWORD;
            $host = self::HOST;
            $db = self::DB;
            $connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $username, $password);
            return $connection;
        }

        protected function queryList($sql, $args){
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($args);
            return $stmt;
        }

    }

?>
```

What should I do in order to access that class PDORepository. I have found some here that talks about using abstract class. But it's not similar to this. Thank you for your help! Newbie here!

Comment: I don't really get why this class is abstract. Besides, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: ^. other notes`$this` refers to the object you're currently in. In index.php you're not in an object context so $this is not defined. Abstract classes are used as a way to create a base class that should be extended to complete the functionality expected in the class. It would seem your class should be a normal (or final) class. You then need to instantiate it with `$db = new PDORepository;`. You will then have some problems with the getConnection method being private (only accessible within the object). I'd recommend starting out simpler and testing the code frequently.

Comment: At whole, this code is just a pile of operators, banged together at random. Let me suggest you to practice  with vanilla PDO for a while. It will save you a lot of headache. Just for the record: the problem with $this is not the only issue here

Answer (score 1):

First problem, you cannot instantiate an abstract class, you have to have a "concrete" class which extends the abstract class.  So I would create a class `UserRepository` which extends `PDORepository`:

```
<?php //pdorepository.php
    abstract class PDORepository{
        const USERNAME="xxxx";
        const PASSWORD="";
        const HOST="xxxxxx";
        const DB="xxxxx";
        private $conn;
        private function getConnection(){
            if (!$this->conn) {
                $username = self::USERNAME;
                $password = self::PASSWORD;
                $host = self::HOST;
                $db = self::DB;
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $username, $password);
            }
            return $this->connection;
        }

        protected function execute($sql, $args = null) {
            return $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->execute($args);
        }
    }

?>
```

---

Now, in your userrepository, we will put your code from index.php, and since you are now doing things *inside of an object*, you can use `$this` without getting an error:

```
<?php //userrepository.php
    require_once 'pdorepository.php';
    class UserRepository extends PDORepository{
        public function init() {
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
                      user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                      account VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                      password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    )";
            try {
                $this->execute($sql);
            } catch(Exception $e){
                echo " " . $e->message();
            }
        }

?>
```

---

Now, with those two classes, you can instantiate an instance of `UserRepository`, and you can then call methods on it:

```
<?php //index.php

require_once 'userrepository.php'
$repository = new UserRepository();
$repository->init();
```

Comment: User is not a database API and thus should never extend the latter.

Comment: @YourCommonSense first off, he's obviously a brand new programmer, so while a software architecture answer might be useful to *you*, in the contect of this question, it would be pointless.  Second, user is not the class I wrote, I wrote userrepository.  A repository is defined as "a central location in which data is stored and managed."  I think a database meets that definition.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate the Dave's answer which is correct explaining the proper architecture in general, but unfortunately, the particular code is rather non-viable, as it keeps a lot of problems from the OP.

To make it proper, we will need 3 files:

**pdo.php** where we will create an instance of PDO class:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$dsn  = "mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8";
$opt  = array(
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

**pdorepository.php**

```
<?php
abstract class PDORepository
{
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    protected function _sql($sql, $args = null)
    {
        if (!$args) {
            return $this->pdo->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

**userrepository.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'pdorepository.php';
class UserRepository extends PDORepository
{
    public function init()
    {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
                  user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                  account VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                  password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
                )";
        $this->_sql($sql);
    }
}
```

and finally our application file:

```
<?php
require_once 'pdo.php';
require_once 'userrepository.php';

$repository = new UserRepository($pdo);
$repository->init();
```

Here the database connection is made only **once** which is critically important. Also a lot of minor issues are fixed. This is the working and usable code.